# How to get particular row from two dimensional array?

Tags: java

```
String[][] array = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
String[][] resultArray = [10][10];
```

i want to store first row of array values to resultArray, how can i do it in java. Please help me

Comment: `String [] firstRow = array[0];`

Comment: Your resultArray is a two dimnentional array

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
String[] resultArray = array[0]; //gets the first row of array
```

Comment: i want to store first row of the array variable to first row of the resultArray variable, without using indexing

Comment: Well...then you will have to hardcode the value, like this: `String[] resultArray = {"a", "b", "c"};`

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] array = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
String[] resultArrayPtr = array[index];
```

if you want to copy you going to have iterate or to use `clone`.

Comment: in resultArrayPtr how can i store first row of array to first item of resultArrayPtr

Comment: @Sathesh by setting `index = 0;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**copies reference**

```
String[][] array = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
String[] resultArray = array[0];
```

**copies values**

```
String[][] array = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
String[] resultArray = new String[array[0].length];
System.arraycopy(array[0],0, resultArray, 0, array[0].length);
```